# Android SQLite MAX function issue

Tags: android, sqlite, max

I want to retrieve rows from table having MAX(col), but MAX(col) return multiple rows if values at col has same data.
I have 2 tables as below:

```
**Table1**
row_id INTEGER (Primary key auto incremented), 
name   TEXT

**Table2**
row_id INTEGER (Primary key auto incremented), 
ref_id INTEGER (Foreign key of Table1(row_id)), 
date_in_long TEXT, 
data   TEXT
```

Following query I am performing to get rows having MAX(date_in_long), expecting single latest entered rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.name, b.row_id, b.ref_id, b.date_in_long, b.data
FROM Table1 a, Table2 b 
WHERE a.row_id=b.ref_id 
AND b.date_in_long =
(SELECT MAX(c.date_in_long) 
 FROM Table2 c 
 WHERE c.ref_id=a.row_id
)
```

Output result would be perfect if date_in_long is having different values against ref_id.. but it returns multiple rows is values are same.
Example

**Table1:**
    row_id  name
    1       aparna
    2       user1
    3       XYZ

**Table2:**
    row_id  ref_id  date_in_long  data
    1       1       98            data1 for aparna
    2       1       100           data2 for aparna
    3       1       100           data3 for aparna
    4       2       200           data1 for user1
    5       2       300           data2 for user1 
    6       3       100           data1 for XYZ

**Result of above query:**

```
row_id  ref_id  name    date_in_long  data
2       1       aparna  100           data2 for aparna
3       1       aparna  100           data3 for aparna
5       2       user1   300           data2 for user1
6       3       XYZ     100           data1 for XYZ
```

**Expected result should be:**

```
row_id  ref_id  name     date_in_long  data
3       1       aparna   100           data3 for aparna
5       2       user1    300           data3 for user1
6       3       XYZ      100           data1 for XYZ
```

Please let me know how issue in above query.

Adding below condition(As solution provided by Alexandar with this post) excluding some rows

```
AND
b.row_id = (Select MAX(c.row_id) from Table2 c where c.ref_id = b.ref_id)
```

**Output after adding above row_id condition:**

```
row_id  ref_id  name     date_in_long  data
3       1       aparna   100           data3 for aparna
6       3       XYZ      100           data1 for XYZ
```

No rows for USER1.

Please let me know how to solve this query.

Thank you,
Regards,
Aparna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query solve my issue.

```
SELECT a.name, b.row_id, b.ref_id, b.date_in_long, b.data, MAX(date_in_long)
FROM Table1 a INNER JOIN Table2 b 
ON a.row_id=b.ref_id 
GROUP BY a.row_id
```

Thank you,
Regards,
Aparna

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the "distinct" keyword doesn't mean "return rows where every value is different from every other row", it means "return rows that are in some way different from each other row".

So even though row_id 2 and 3 have the same ref_id, they have a different row_id and data column-  Hence, they're unique rows.

One option is to add an extra condition so that only the max row_id for a specific ref-id is respected.

The added condition would look something like this.

```
AND
b.row_id = (Select MAX(c.row_id) from Table2 c where c.ref_id = b.ref_id)
```

Comment: Edited question with the output using above condition.